# how can i set this output in one line ( center )

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
    <div style="float: left;">

        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>

        <input list="123" placeholder="search" style="border: none; background-color: whitesmoke; margin-left: 5px; outline: none;">
            <datalist id="123">

            </datalist>

    </div>

    <div style="float: right;">

        <a href=""><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span style="color: grey;">Divyang Pipaliya</span>

        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="color: grey; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218); border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 20px;"></i>

    </div>

</div>
```

**how can i set this output in one line ( center ). have tried the flex method also but the result was the same.**

Comment: Do you want to center the Search, Name and notification icon in one line while it's center?

Comment: yes in one line

Comment: I added an answer that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with flexbox

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(76, 136, 248);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper i {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

i.fa-user {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">

  <div>

    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>

    <input list="123" placeholder="search" style="border: none; background-color: whitesmoke; margin-left: 5px; outline: none;">
    <datalist id="123">

        </datalist>

  </div>

  <div>

    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span style="color: grey;">Divyang Pipaliya</span>

    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="color: grey; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218); border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 20px;"></i>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
   .header-top{background:#000; color:#fff;display:flex;align-items:center;padding:10px; justify-content: space-around;}
  .header-top ul{list-style:none;padding:0; margin:0;display:flex;align-items:center; }
  .header-top ul li{padding:0px 10px;} 
</style>

 <div class="header-top">
   <div class="logo">Hello</div>
    <ul>
       <li>Menu</li>
       <li>About Us</li>
       <li>Contact US</li>
       <li>Login</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Center in one line using a `<table>`. I removed some of the extra code that was in there, but you get the point from this.

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <center>    
          <div>
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <input list="123" placeholder="search" style="border: none; background-color: whitesmoke; margin-left: 5px; outline: none;">
      
            <span style="color: grey;">Divyang Pipaliya</span>
              
          </div></tr>
    </table>
```